# Import existing mult-rep CVS project folder into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I wish to import an existing CVS managed project into Eclipse. I am currently trying to shift my work on to the Eclipse IDE. Some details about my project and environment below.

I'm working in Linux Ubuntu, the project folder is located on a mounted shared network drive, I have installed the "Eclipse CVS Client" plug-in for my version of Eclipse (Helios).

I've tried many ways for eclipse to use my existing folder as a project and recognize the CVS data in the CVS folders.

I have done the following options:

1. Created a new project, selected existing source, located my project folder and clicked OK to finish creating. In the end the CVS files weren't automatically read.
2. Did the same as above and after project creation I wen to the option "project menu->team->share project", it asks me to choose a repository and doesn't automatically find the CVS information in the subfolders.

I have set-up both repositories in my eclipse and can browse the repositories through the CVS browser.

My project directory layout is like this:

```
+-Project Folder (no CVS folder at this level)
+---Repo A folder
+-----CVS meta-info folder is INSIDE, along with all checked out files from Repo A
+
+---Repo B folder 
+-----CVS meta-info folder is INSIDE, along with all checked out files from Repo B
+
+-(couple of random files, not in CVS)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just right-click on your project and click Team -> Share Project. Eclipse will detect that the folder is already shared and resolve the connection with CVS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I cannot answer your question (I think it should work as you explaned) but I might have a workaround. Could you remove or rename the existing folder and do a fresh check out from your eclipse/CVS repository exploring view?

Comment: Hmm I could but it would make my life a lot easier if I could just import my existing checked out files. Main reason being is that there are lot of checked out files from various modules (under same branch).